# what's the role of (char) Right before ((unsigned char) ~0 >> 1)?

Tags: c, binary, char

I'm a beginner to C.

This code does what `SCHAR_MIN` in <limits.h> do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Minimum Signed Char %d\n",-(char)((unsigned char) ~0 >> 1) - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I understood:
`(unsigned char)` takes the bits of an unsigned char which is "0000 0000".
`~0` gives the complement of it which is "1111 1111" and `>> 1` turns the "1" on the left side of "1111 1111" to 0, so it will give "0111 1111". Converting "0111 1111" to integer will give 127 which is the maximum signed char. To get the minimum, we need to invert 127, so we multiply it by `-` to get -127 and `- 1` gives us -128 which is the minimum. Tell me if I misunderstood something.

**Question**:

what's the role of `(char)` here? Right before `((unsigned char) ~0 >> 1)`? What does it represent?

Comment: The role of `(char)` is to convert the result of the right expression to a char. This is a *cast*. By the way, do not consider `char` is always 8 bits!

Comment: @fpiette Why would we convert the result to char? if I remove it, it'll work just fine. what difference does it make? Is it to make the bit size smaller?

Comment: remove the `- 1` and then try with and without `(char)`

Comment: @Eraklon: The results are the same.

Comment: @Eraklon Nothing obvious changed...

Comment: @EricPostpischil Whops, yepp. I also put parenthesizes around `~0 >> 1` like `(~0 >> 1)`.

Comment: Its not important to do this tho, the point is to just explore what happens when playing around with the code.

Comment: Which `<limits.h>` do you use? Mine on Debian has `#define SCHAR_MIN (-128)`.

Answer (score 1):

This code may have arisen as a pattern that works for all signed integer types, as the cast is necessary for `int` and wider types, although it is not needed for `char` in ordinary C implementations.

Consider `-(Type)((unsigned Type) ~0 >> 1) - 1)`. With the `<code>(<i>Type</i>)</code>` cast, we get the desired negative result. Without it, we would get a wrong positive result: When `Type` is `int`, and two’s complement is used, `((unsigned <i>Type</i>) ~0 >> 1` is an `unsigned int` with its high bit off and others on. Applying unary `-` to this would produce an `unsigned int`, and so would the subtraction. So the result would be positive, not the desired negative value. With the cast `(Type)`, the value is converted to the signed type before the unary `-`, so a negative value is produced.

Thus, this code likely arose by using the pattern `-(Type)((unsigned Type) ~0 >> 1) - 1)` for all the signed integer types. Even though the cast is not necessary for `char` or `short` in ordinary C implementations, it remains there because simple substitutions were made when drafting the code in a pattern.

This also explains why the cast is to `char` instead of `signed char`: It was a simple substitution of `long long int`, `long int`, `int`, `short`, and `char` for `Type`, neglecting the special treatment of `char` versus `signed char`. (This is not a problem in ordinary C implementations where `char` is narrower than `int`, but using `signed char` would make the code work in exotic C implementations where `char` is the same width as `int`.)

Inspecting the `limits.h` file you found this in would likely show the same pattern for the other types.

Comment: Did some more testing, `-(char)((unsigned char) ~0 >> 1) - 1 < 0` is false on systems where `CHAR_MAX==UINT_MAX` (and using a 2-complement). If it should work on systems where `char` has the same size as an `int`, then the `char` must be replaced by a `signed char`. Of course, `printf()` still works because `printf()` interprets the value as signed.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: As the answer states, the conversion to `char` makes the expression work with `char` the same width as `int` “provided `char` is signed in that case.” And, in discussing why it works in that case, it notes that `char` must be “presumably signed.” So why are you critiquing, and presumably voting down, for an issue that is covered in the answer and correctly covered?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: In any case, further thought shows how this code may have arisen, so I have rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- The integer constant `0` is of type `int`, so `~0` results in an `int` value such as 0xFFFFFFFF (assuming 32 bit). Which is actually a negative value corresponding to decimal `-1` in 2's complement.
- In case we're only interested in the least significant byte, we can mask out that one by casting to `unsigned char`, ending up with `0xFF`. That way we also drop the signed format, for now.
- Then the `>>` operator implicitly promotes our temporary `unsigned char` operand back up to `int`, but since the value `0xFF` (`255`) fits inside an `int`, that's the value we get. We end up bit-shifting a signed type but has a positive value.
- `0xFF >> 1` gives `0x7F` = 127. In fact the whole `((unsigned char) ~0 >> 1)` is just a complicated way of typing `127`. Because on all normal systems with 8 bit bytes, that's what we get.
- Now this is explicitly converted to `char` with a cast. It's still the same value 127.
- `-` gives `-127`. The unary `-` operator implicit promotes the result back to `int`.
- `-127 - 1 = -128`.

Note that the signedness of `char` is implementation-defined. It might as well be unsigned, in which case the cast doesn't make much sense. The implicit promotion by the `-` gives us a signed `int` anyway, so the cast to `char` achieves nothing.

See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) for details about integer promotion.